# Skip an iteration in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, feature-class, iterator

I am trying to iterate through some feature classes, named "*Hos*_AllPatients2014", and select the certain data and name it "*Hos*_IP", then export it to the corresponding folder "*Hos*". I have already made folders for each "*Hos*" that contain another layer I had to make for each. However, there are some "AllPatients2014" feature classes for which I do not have a folder. I thought I deleted them all out, but found out halfway through my model running that it had an error and stopped. I would have liked to have had the model contain a portion to check if "*Hos*_IP" already exists, and if so move on to the next iteration. Instead, I had to create a new folder with the remaining "AllPatients2014" and started the model again.

I would like to find out how to get the model to make this check for a feature class and skip to the next iteration if it exists. I would also be interested to figure out if the folder for "*Hos*" exists, and if not, create a folder for it and go ahead and export the data like the rest.

I don't know how helpful a picture of my model will be, but it is included. Also open to hearing how I can refine the whole thing.[image: Iterate FC]

Comment: This can be done easily in python/arcpy.

Comment: Have you seen/tried this before, http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w00000022000000. This can be incorporated to the second part of your question as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/in-python-check-if-a-directory-exists-and-create-it-if-necessary

Comment: Yes, I knew it could be done with python. However, I am unsure of the wording of the script. The example from the help index seems to be more complicated than what I need. Does anyone have an idea of the script I would write?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement if-then-else logic with Branching

http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/automating_your_work_with_models/branching_colon_implementing_if_then_else_logic.htm